# Proving that the existence of given limit implies that bounded $f:[a,b]\to\mathbf R$ is Riemann integrable

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, riemann-sum, riemann-integration

I'm struggling a bit with this problem I've been given. It regards Riemann integrability for a function $f$. It reads like this:

> Decide whether the statement is true or false by giving a proof if it is true and a counterxample if it is false:
>
> "Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \textbf{R}$ be a bounded function. Then $f$ is Riemann-integrable on $\textbf{R}$ if and only if
>   $$L:=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(x_{k}*)\frac{b-a}{n}\in\textbf{R},$$
>
> where $f(x_{k}^{*})$ denotes the middle point of the interval $$\left[a+\frac{(k-1)(b-a)}{n},\ a+\frac{k(b-a)}{n}\right].$$ In this case, $L=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx$."

I've proven one direction:

($\Rightarrow$) Suppose $f$ is Riemann-integrable. Then $U(P,f)-L(P,f)<\epsilon$ for some partition P. Let this partition $P$ be $P=(a, a+\frac{b-a}{n}, ... , a+\frac{(n-1)(b-a)}{n}, b)$. Now, with this partition and with $x_{k}^*$ as the middle point of $[x_{k-1},x_{k}]$ we have:

$|\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(x_{k}^{*})\frac{b-a}{n}-\int_{b}^{a}f(x)\,dx|<\epsilon\Rightarrow\text{lim}_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(x_{k}*)\frac{b-a}{n}=L\in\textbf{R}$.

Furthermore, $L=\int_{b}^{a}f(x)\,dx$.

Now it is the proof for the other direction that has me confused. I understand that I want to use that the given limit exists to aid me in proving that f is Riemann integrable and most of my attempts boil down to showing that:

$U(P,f)-L(P,f)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(M_{k}-m_{k})\Delta_{x_{i}}\leq|\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(x_{k}*)\frac{b-a}{n}-L|<\epsilon$

Where $M_{k}$ is the supremum of $f$ in the interval $[x_{k-1}, x_{k}]$ and $m_{k}$ is the infimum.

Am I heading in the right direction? Is there something I haven't seen? Is the statement even true or does it break when trying to prove the converse? Would appreciate all kinds of hints, explanation or help possible.

Comment: If you have problems finding a proof, spend some time looking for counterexamples.

Comment: @DanielFischer I've been thinking around examples but I think I may not fully understand what I'm asked to counter. Would it be enough for me to find a function that is not Riemann Integrable which meets the property of having the limit of the sum exist in R?

Comment: Yes, exactly. One (bounded) function that isn't Riemann-integrable but such that the limit in question exists proves that the assertion of equivalence is false. Use the fact that the partitions and the $x_k^{\ast}$ are prescribed to guide you. Choose for example $[a,b] = [0,1]$ to have something concrete.

Comment: @DanielFischer Okay, fine. I think I have an idea. If I let [a,b] be the interval [0,1] and let f(x) be the mapping that takes f(x) to 1 if x is rational and to 0 if x is irrational then f is not Riemann-integrable. However, the given sum would then become 1 and thus the limit would also be 1 which is in **R**. However, this is not Riemann-integrable and thus the statement cannot be true in general.
Would you say this would suffice as a counterexample? It doesn't feel elegant at all but it seems to be enough to me.

Comment: Of course it suffices as a counterexample. For a general claim, one counterexample suffices to disprove the claim. And while it is not mind-blowingly elegant, it _is_ an elegant example. It's simple to describe, and clearly exposes why the condition is not sufficient to imply Riemann integrability.

Comment: You need to work on your argument in the other direction. You get the existence of one no further specified partition $P$ for given $ϵ$. You can not in the next step claim that this $P$ is an equidistant partition. You can also not claim that there is an equidistant subordinated partition. You need some argument about all partitions with a maximal interval length.